# Invalid type: Component.Apex.Page + Salesforce

Tags: apex, managed-package

I am getting an exception email from a client who has installed my Managed Package in his org. The error message I receive is:

Apex script unhandled trigger exception by user/organization: xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx

**"ContentDocument" Trigger (AfterUpdate)**

caused by: line 30, column 39: **Invalid type: Component.Apex.Page**

Also, I cross check the same in my Dev Org, it is correct and code saves fine, no compilation error when saving the class code.

In my code it just inserts a list of custom sObject based on some conditions that's it.

How can I fix this error?